# Composite primary key with many to one relation ship does not support mapping error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa, persistence

I have three entities which form the association relationship by having composite primary keys that also foreign key of other tables. These are the implementation of these entites:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTSCOURSES", schema = "GPA")
@NamedQuery(name = "getAllStdCrs", query = "SELECT sc FROM StudentsCourses sc")
@IdClass(StudentCourseId.class)
public class StudentsCourses implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="studentID", insertable=false, updatable= false)
private int studentID;  

@Id
@Column(name="crsID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private int crsID;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="STUDENTID")
Student student;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CRSID")
Course course;

public StudentsCourses() {
    super();
}

public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
    this.studentID = studentID;
}
public int getStudentID() {
    return studentID;
}
public void setCrsID(int crsID) {
    this.crsID = crsID;
}
public int getCrsID() {
    return crsID;
}   
}
```

Course entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSES", schema = "GPA")
@NamedQuery(name = "getAllCourses", query = "SELECT c FROM Course c")
public class Course implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="CRSID")
private int crsID;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="course", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Assesment> assesments;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="course", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<StudentsCourses> studentCourses;

public Course() {
    super();
}

public int getCrsID() {
    return crsID;
}

public void setCrsID(int crsID) {
    this.crsID = crsID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAssesments(Set<Assesment> assesments) {
    this.assesments = assesments;
}

public Set<Assesment> getAssesments() {
    return assesments;
}

public void setStudentCourses(Set<StudentsCourses> studentCourses) {
    this.studentCourses = studentCourses;
}

public Set<StudentsCourses> getStudentCourses() {
    return studentCourses;
}
}
```

Student Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS", schema = "GPA")
@NamedQuery(name = "getAllStudents", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s")
public class Student implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int studentID;
private String studentName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Assesment> assesments;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<StudentsCourses> studentCourses;

public Student() {
    super();
}

public int getStudnetID() {
    return studentID;
}

public void setStudnetID(int stdID) {
    this.studentID = stdID;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setAssesments(Set<Assesment> assesments) {
    this.assesments = assesments;
}

public Set<Assesment> getAssesments() {
    return assesments;
}

public void setStudentCourses(Set<StudentsCourses> studentCourses) {
    this.studentCourses = studentCourses;
}

public Set<StudentsCourses> getStudentCourses() {
    return studentCourses;
}
}
```

When I try to lanuch the program I am getting following error:

```
[4/5/13 0:30:15:243 EDT] 00000028 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[com.gpa.app.servlet.LoginServlet]: <openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1141200 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Field "com.gpa.app.entities.Course.studentCourses" cannot declare that it is mapped by another field. Its mapping strategy (org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.HandlerFieldStrategy) does not support mapping by another field.
```

What could be the cause of the prob. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What you are trying to do should be possible but I do not have time right now to figure out what is wrong. However i would like to point out that StudentCourses looks very much like it maps to a link table. So the StudentCourses entity only establishes links between Student and Course. If that is right you could leave out the StudentCourses entity and make a direct ManyToMany mapping between Student and Course.

Comment: try this :
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade={CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true) 
@JoinColumn(name="columnName")
private Set<StudentsCourses> studentCourses;

Comment: @Eelke thanks for your comment. According to my application scope many to many relationship would not suite. I will have problem retrieving all the courses for one particular student if I have one student exist more than one time in the database. That's y I chose one to many instead. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @Neron Thanks for your answer and I tried your code, still getting the same error.

Comment: Had another look and can't find anything wrong with the mapping. EclipseLink also finds no fault with it. I noticed in the error you use a snapshot release of openjpa maybe you should try another version.

Comment: @Eelke Thanks for all of your time to solve my problem. I finally solved the problem, of course with your help. The problem was in my idClass I didn't implemented hascode, equal method and didn't implement serializable.I didn't know I have to implement those. Anyways, at least I learned something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was in my @Id classes. In that class I didn't implemented equal and hash code method and also didn't implemented Serializable. After done that everything worked smoothly. Thanks to Eelke, he gave me the idea to try in different version and it helped me to find out the cause.

My modified code in looks like this:

```
public class StudentCourseId implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int studentID;
private int crsID;

public StudentCourseId() {
}

public StudentCourseId(int studentID, int crsID) {
    this.studentID = studentID;
    this.crsID = crsID;
}

public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
    this.studentID = studentID;
}

public int getStudentID() {
    return studentID;
}

public void setCrsID(int crsID) {
    this.crsID = crsID;
}

public int getCrsID() {
    return crsID;
}
public int hashCode() {
    return studentID + crsID;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return ((o instanceof StudentCourseId)
            && studentID == ((StudentCourseId) o).getStudentID() && crsID == ((StudentCourseId) o)
                .getCrsID());
}
    }
 public int getCrsID() {
    return crsID;
}   
}
```

Hope it helps for someone in the future.

Thanks,
Sas